# Date 1/3 of the way between two dates in R

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I want to find something a little more general than the midpoint function for two dates in R.

I have a dataframe with two columns of dates (before and after) and I want to make a new column with the dates that are 1/3 of the way between the before and after dates. Date format is '%Y-%m-%d'

```
before = c('2021-06-01', '2021-06-05', '2021-03-01', '2021-01-01')
after = c('2023-05-01', '2022-06-15', '2024-03-01', '2021-01-17')
df = data.frame(before, after)
```

I realize I could just calculate the days in between, divide that by 3 and add that to the before date. But I'm wondering if there's a function that already exists that does that

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that would be a built-in function to any package, it's too niche. That said, it is one line of code:

```
cut_int <- \(x, y, n) x + (y - x)/n

df |>
    mutate(across(everything(), ymd)) |>
    mutate(out = cut_int(before, after, 3))
```

Another way, is to get the sequence of numbers, from which we can select the second element (0/3, 1/3, 2/3, 3/3 means a 4 element list)

```
df |>
  mutate(across(everything(), ymd)) |>
  mutate(out = as.Date(map2_dbl(before, after, ~ seq(.x, .y, length.out = 4)[2])))
```

Comment: I see. For some reason, I'm running into issues with the datetime. It says Error : Problem with `mutate()` column `out`.
ℹ `out = cut_int(before, after, n)`.
✖ non-numeric argument to binary operator

 When I run the first method

Comment: I just ran the code again, and it runs the same. Are you running it on the same dataframe in the example, with the same code? Have you loaded dplyr?

Comment: yeah, I'm running it on a cluster so that's probably causing the issues.

Comment: hmmm I've never run R on a cluster, but I'll take your word for it. Test it on a regular computer and lmk if it still works! :-)